# Footprint naming convention

Tags: symbol

I've been creating a library with symbol for OrCad according to the naming convention IPC-7351 and I cannot understand one thing. What does the letter "N" stand for in the example given below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "N" means "nominal". It refers to the density level. The density levels for the PCB footprints according to IPC-7351 are:

- Maximum - M
- Nominal - N
- Least - L
- Manufacturer Specified - Q

For more information, you can look here ([Footprint Naming Conventions])[1](http://blog.optimumdesign.com/pcb-library-organization-part-two-footprint-naming-conventions)

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you for your help and time